# Date wrong in PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following code and I'm able to add to today's date, but if the existing date is before today it still returns today's date. MySQL data is stored as a y-m-d string.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$oldate = "SELECT date FROM signup WHERE user='$user'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $oldate) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

if (strtotime($result1) < $date) {
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$months months", strtotime($date)));
} else {
    $date1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+$months months", strtotime($result1)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing timestamp value ($result1) with string  $date1.You need to cast your $date1 to timestamp as well. Change your if condition to make it work as follow:

```
if(strtotime($result1)<strtotime($date))
{

   ....
}
else
{ 
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're above code isn't working is because `$result1` won't be a date. `mysqli_query` will return an instance of `mysqli_result` when you've performed a successful select query.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php :

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You can use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` to get the information you want:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
$rowDate = $row['date'];
```

Also, as Prada pointed out you can't not compare dates in the way you have in your question, however, you could do something like:

```
if (strtotime($rowDate) < strtotime($date))
```

Alternatively, you could use `DateTime` and have something like:

```
$oldate = "SELECT date FROM signup WHERE user='$user'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $oldate) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

$now = new DateTime;
$date = new DateTime($row['date']);

$date1 = $date < $now
    ? $now->modify("+$months months")->format('Y-m-d')
    : $date->modify("+$months months")->format('Y-m-d');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Still didnt' work.  Instead of using $result1 in the "mysqli_fetch_assoc(", do you mean $oldate?

Comment: @user7314100 No, because `$oldDate` is just a string and `mysqli_fetch_assoc` expects to be passed an instance of `mysqli_result` which should be returned from `mysqli_query`. What do you get if you add `die(print_r($row));` right under `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);`?

Comment: I get - Array ( [date] => 2017-03-14 ) 1

Comment: @user7314100 Ok, so how isn't it working? Are you getting an error? If not what are you expecting and what are you getting?

Comment: I get a return value as if it's using today's date.  If I add 2 months it's 2017-3-15, not 2017-5-15 since 2017-3-15 is the original value.

Comment: @user7314100 Just to double check but you're definitely using `$date1` and not `$date`?

Comment: Right -  ("UPDATE signup SET date='$date1'

Comment: Ok, I forgot to change both the if statement and the $date1 references to $rowDate.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @user7314100 Did this answer your question?